# How to remove the root folder name from codeigniter application

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting, shared-hosting

I have my website hosted at `https://www.webdomain.com/`
The hosted website at the above domain IS NOT CODEIGNITER

On the server, at the location `my_username/public_html/www/myproject`, a Codeigniter application is hosted.

Meaning, to access a `controller` and its `function` in `myproject` application.

I use the following URL

`https://webdomain.com/myproject/controller/function`

As you may have already noticed, `myproject` is the root folder of the Codeigniter application

I've been trying to remove `myproject` from the URL, but with no luck.

I've gone through several questions on stack overflow, but as I figured it out, all of those questions refer to project directories, that are not necessarily application root directory. In my case, I want to remove the name of the root directory `myproject` from the URL.

This is my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

Comment: Why not point your domain `https://webdomain.com/` directly to `my_username/public_html/www/myproject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^myproject/(.*)$ $1 [R]
```

This need to be in the root folder, I strongly recommend you go with @vivek_23 suggestion in the comment.

Comment: Pointing domain will not work as I am using it ss the main website, then the CodeIgniter application is a backend for our mobile apps

Comment: Then you can create subdomain and point it to ```myproject.```

Comment: just for  more clearfication, your are running the main website  from my_username/public_html/www direcotry and your backend code in my_username/public_html/www/myproject/ direcotry 
am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to set route in route.php file?

```
$route['controller/function'] = 'myproject/controller/function';
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, however, this did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `.htaccess`. I mainly used this on the `localhost` machine. This `.htaccess` file should be in the `root` of `myproject` folder. Here is the documentation for more information https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /myproject/
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Hope this will help to out :)